# I want to send slug of the product in the anchor tag

Tags: php

I want to send a slug of the products which dynamically come from the database in the anchor tag to the product `details page`. and then I want to filter products according to that slug comes in the URL.
But here is some error. when I clicked the `anchor tag` it goes to the page and says `Object not found!`.
Here is the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukXsd.png)

```
<a href="products/<?=$row['slug'];?>" class="block2-name dis-block s-text3 p-b-5">
   <?php echo $row['product_title']; ?>
</a>
```

and this is the `details page` code where I want to filter that product according to the slug. but I don't know how to write the exact query for that.

```
<?php
  require_once('includes/header.php');
  @$slug= $_REQUEST['slug'];
  $displayProduct = "SELECT 
  products.*,categories.cat_title,categories.cat_id from products join 
  categories on categories.cat_id = products.cat_id where 
  product_id='$product_id'";
  $resultProduct = mysqli_query($conn,$displayProduct);
  $rowProducts = mysqli_fetch_array($resultProduct);
?>
```

After the `where` condition I want to write this code `slug='$slug'`. But it not works.

Comment: `$_REQUEST['slug']` isn't set anywhere in the URL requested in your image

Comment: but the anchor tag sends me to another page and shows Object Not found!.

Comment: how I can send the slug in the url? like this 'http://app.test/products/men-new-watches'.

Comment: Probably because the page is looking for an empty slug? I'm just guessing here. Have you tried adding `?slug=men-new-watches` to the end of that URL in your image?

Comment: Could it be that your site is currently missing some rewrite rules?

Comment: i have tried some rewrite rules but it also not working.

Comment: Have you tried a.test/products/men-new-watches?slug=men-new-watches ? If that works then you need to work on your rewrite rules.

Comment: Please provide details about the environment, PHP version, web server, configuration of the web server (like rewrite rules), framework, etc.